# Is an "in-page survey" a good way of retrieving useful users opinions?

Tags: interface, surveys

I'm thinking about implementing a different means of retrieving users' opinions about my company websites.

This is how I imagine this feature:

1. On every page of the websites, a non intrusive `position: fixed` box asks visitors a single question about his user experience on the current page
2. Each page has a different set of questions (since the goal of each page is different)
3. Only one click is needed to answer a question (radio buttons with "yes", "no", "no opinion" options)
4. Submission is AJAX driven in order to avoid interruption of visitors' tasks
5. The above point must be understood by the visitor so that (s)he doesn't fear clicking the radio boxes
6. Submission sends data into a database
7. Some php filtering procedure will prevent submissions by robots or people trying to abuse the system

My question (as in the title) :

**Is this "in-page survey" a good way of retrieving useful users opinions?**

I want to make sure that :

1. this way of doing things is really unobtrusive from the user's point of view
2. the collected data will be useful enough to allow a better conversion rate

Comment: Your question is too broad and you are rather asking will it help your business or not. If you could narrow your question down to single specific question then you will be able to get useful response on that. Otherwise its a matter of general opinion instead of professional advice.

Comment: How big is the company website? Are there many levels of navigation? Will the user end up seeing this feedback input on return visits? What if they only answer on certain pages and not others?

Comment: @Salman Thanks for the input. I edited the post. I hope this is better.

Answer (score 1):

I think general page analytics information combined with a structured survey will provide you with similar results, but not intrude on the user activities of the website. It also takes less effort and is easier to maintain even if your website content and structure changes. However, if the website is small and it gives you the flexibility to ask more insightful questions or gather more meaningful responses then there is no reason not to at least give it a try (maybe A/B test it?). You can always let the users be the judge of that decision, since it will be more meaningful and relevant to the answers you will get here.

Comment: Thanks but what do you mean by "structured survey"? Are you talking about what's more commonly called "structured interviews"?

Comment: By structured survey I am referring to something that can be standardized and data collected in a consistent way, which can then be analyzed or compared against other data. This is because analytics data provide an overall picture without exact context, and structured survey or analysis allows you to focus on specific topics of interest.